# datagridview in c# windows forms application

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm working on `DataGridView` in C# `WindowsForms` application using SQL server 2005 and i added 1 column i.e "name" to my `DataGridView` and displayed it by selecting row to text box but it shows only one column i.e "Name" to text box. But i have other columns like city state, that I have not added to my `DataGridView`
Is there any way to display all the database record by clicking on single column "Name " from `DataGridView` to `Textboxes`?

private void `dataGridView1_CellClick`(object sender,`DataGridViewCellEventArgs` e){
            i = e.RowIndex;
            DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

```
        textBox1.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        String str = "server=PC2-PC;database=demo;Integrated Security=true";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
        con.Open();
           if (e.RowIndex != -1)
        {
            textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[Name].Value == null ? "" : dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[Name].Value.ToString();
            CallData();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Don't post a screenshot of your code, paste them as text.

Comment: Also, did you open your SQL connection? I can't see con.Open

Comment: yes SQL connection is open

Answer (score 0):

with your solution, you can build other columns in DataGridView and change Visible to false. in this way you can fill them when you filling Name Column and use their's data when user click on a row and show in TextBoxes.

but this way of using database in form events, is not a standard code.